# Python Coin change SO CLOSE

Tags: python

I am doing the coin-change problem. I have finished the problem in that it prints out how many coins I need to make the least amount of change possible, but how do I change my program so that it also prints those coins??

Here is a sample `I/O`:

input: `coin_change(48, [1, 5, 10, 25, 50])`

output: `[6, [25, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1]]`

Currently my code only returns the `6`.

**by the way, this must be done with recursion only. no loops are allowed**

Code:

```
def change(C, V):
    def min_coins(i, aC):
        if aC == 0:
            return 0
        elif i == -1 or aC < 0:
            return float('inf')
        else:
            return min(min_coins(i-1, aC), 1 + min_coins(i, aC-V[i]))
    return min_coins(len(V)-1, C)
```

Comment: If I were grading this homework assignment, I'd doc you some points for picking nondescriptive variable names like C, V, 0, and aC. Makes it hard to figure out what's going on

Comment: What about iterative higher-order functions, e.g. reduce or map? Can you use those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different version of your program:

```
def change(C, V, res=None):
    res = [] if res is None else res
    if len(V) == 0:
        return len(res), res
    maxx = max(V)
    V.remove(maxx)
    ans = C//maxx
    if ans == 0 and maxx < C :
        res += [maxx] * ans
        return len(res), res
    else:
        res += [maxx] * ans
        return  change(C % maxx, V, res)

print change(48,[1, 5, 10, 25, 50])
print change(30,[25, 10, 2, 3, 1])
```

**output:**

```
(6, [25, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1])
(3, [25, 3, 2])
```

PS: I'll add an explanation if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. I get it except for this one part. What does this line do?

if res is None else res

Comment: @user1681664 `res` is used to store the answer, but for the first tome when `change()` is called (`change(48,[1,5,10,25,50])`), we didn't provided any value for `res`, so inside the change function res is assigned a value of `[]` if it's `None` otherwise res=`res`. It is a ternary operator in python.