# Use a while loop to continue deducting change from amount when quarters are used up

Tags: python, python-3.x

The issue that I am having is that I can't seem to get the quarters, when they run out, to start using the dimes. I've been working at this for a couple days (as embarrassing as that is) on this stereotypical change making machine. I dont know if it is just that my indentation is off or if my code needs to be rewritten. Honestly, any help will do.
P.S. cant use dictionary,  or any thing fancy.

```
pennies = 10
nickels = 10
dimes = 10
quarters = 10

print("\nWelcome to change-making program.")
in_str = input("\nEnter the purchase price (xx.xx) or `q' to quit: ")

while in_str.lower() != 'q':
    dollar_str, cents_str = in_str.split(".")

    if in_str.lower() == 'q':
        quit()

    in_int = int(float(in_str) * 100)

    if in_int < 0:
        print("Error: purchase price must be non-negative.")
        in_str = input("\nEnter the purchase price (xx.xx) or `q' to quit: ")

    if in_int > 0:
        payment = input("\nInput dollars paid: ")
        payment_int = int(float(payment) * 100)
        change = payment_int - in_int

        #determines if there payment input
        if payment_int < in_int:
            print("Error: Insufficient payment.")
            payment = input("\nInput dollars paid: ")
            payment_int = int(float(payment) * 100)


        if change == 0:
            print("No change.")
        print("\nCollect Payment Below:")

        #determines how many quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies are left
        while change  >= 25 and quarters > 0:
            quarters_spent = change // 25
            change = (change - (quarters_spent * 25))
            quarters = quarters - quarters_spent
            if quarters <= 0:
                quarters_spent = quarters_spent + quarters
                new_change = ((quarters_spent) * 25)
                quarters = 0
                change = change + new_change
                print(quarters_spent, "Quarters")
            else:
                print(quarters_spent, "Quarters")
            change = change
            if change < 25 or quarters <= 0:
                dimes_spent = change // 10
                change = (change - (dimes_spent * 10))
                dimes = dimes - dimes_spent
                if dimes <= 0:
                    dimes_spent = dimes_spent + dimes
                    new_change = (dimes_spent) * 10
                    dimes = 0
                    change = change + new_change
                    print(dimes_spent, "Dimes")
                else:
                    print(dimes_spent, "Dimes")

                if change < 10 or dimes <= 0:
                    nickels_spent = change // 5
                    change = (change - (nickels_spent * 5))
                    nickels = nickels - nickels_spent
                    if nickels <= 0:
                        new_change = (nickels_spent) * 5
                        nickels_spent = nickels_spent + nickels
                        nickels = 0
                        change = change + new_change
                        print(nickels_spent, "Nickels")
                    else:
                        print(nickels_spent, "Nickels")

                    if change < 5 or nickels <= 0:
                        pennies_spent = change // 1
                        change = (change - (pennies_spent * 1))
                        pennies = pennies - pennies_spent
                        if pennies <= 0:
                            pennies_spent = pennies_spent + pennies
                            print(pennies_spent, "Pennies")
                            print("Error: ran out of coins.")
                            pennies = 0
                            print("\nStock: ", quarters, "Quarters, ", dimes, " Dimes, ", nickels,
                            " Nickels, ", pennies, " Pennies ")
                            quit()
                        else:
                            print(pennies_spent, "Pennies")


        print("\nStock: ", quarters, "Quarters, ", dimes, " Dimes, ", nickels, " Nickels, ", pennies, " Pennies ")

        in_str = input("\nEnter the purchase price (xx.xx) or `q' to quit: ")



        pennies = pennies
        nickels = nickels
        dimes = dimes
        quarters = quarters
```

Here is my sample output(the last one is incorrect because the values output in the "Collect Payment Below" should be 5 Q, 5 D, and 3 P):

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Coin change SO CLOSE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535513/python-coin-change-so-close)

Comment: i cant use def in mine, that's why i am having trouble

Comment: Just make the function your main program.  Grab the input and go through the process.  Alternately, just research "Python coin change".

Comment: I can't use functions in my program due to the instructions that i was given

Comment: I understand.  Take the code inside the function and slap it into your main program.  Alter the variable names as needed to make your input / output and the code-formerly-inside-the-function match properly.

Answer (score 1):

The basic flaw is that you've made the logic flow overly complex.  You have a loop outside nested if statements to handle each coin.  Somewhere in managing all of these variables and decisions, you've fumbled a bit of counter logic.

The solution is simpler than that:

```
Determine quarters needed; subtract from total
Determine dimes need; subtract from total
Determine nickels needed; subtract from total
Remaining total is pennies needed.
```

Each step is a simple integer division, which you've already done.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: So, should this all be wrapped in one while loop or do they need to part of separate loops? Actually i think i got it. I'll post if i dont

Comment: They aren't loops at all.  The only loop in the program is the "quit" check.  This logic replaces the code starting at **while change >= 25**